# State setter is returning undefined for an existing value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have these 2 state variables:

```
const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState("")
const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState("")
```

and I have the following that returns an object:

```
const token = await getToken(code) // code taken from prop
```

getToken returns the object:

```
{'accessToken' : result.access_token, 'refreshToken' : result.refresh_token}
```

This is where the issue happens:

```
setAccessToken(token.accessToken)
setRefreshToken(token.refreshToken)
```

I can `console.log(token.accessToken)` and `token.refreshToken`, and I get the values I need, but for whatever reason `setAccessToken` and `setRefreshToken` don't seem to set those values, because when I attempt to console.log(accessToken) and refreshToken, it says those values are undefined.

Full code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import getPlaylists from '../api/getPlaylists'
import { Button, } from '@mui/material'
import tokenRefresh from '../api/tokenRefresh'
import getToken from '../api/getToken'


const section = ({ code }) => {


// const [code, setCode] = useState(code)
const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState("")
const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState("")
const [playlists, setPlaylists] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("COMPONENT CODE", code)
}, [])


const handleClickButton = async () => {
    if(!accessToken && !refreshToken) {
        const token = await getToken(code)
        setAccessToken(token.accessToken)
        setRefreshToken(token.refreshToken)
        console.log("if", accessToken, refreshToken)
    }
    else {
        const token = await tokenRefresh(refreshToken)
        setAccessToken(token.accessToken)
        setRefreshToken(token.refreshToken)
        console.log("else", accessToken, refreshToken)
    }

    const retrievedPlaylists = await getPlaylists(accessToken)
    console.log("retrievedPlaylists",retrievedPlaylists)
    setPlaylists(retrievedPlaylists)
    // const playlists = await getPlaylists(token)
}

return ( 
<div>
<Button onClick={() => handleClickButton()} variant='outlined'> Load the playlists! </Button>
</div>
)
}
export default section
```

Comment: To answer this question, it's probably important to know where the async/await code is being used, and where the state setters are being called. React doesn't play nice with async/await, so you might need to have it set up properly with a `useEffect` hook. Consider sharing the entire source code of the component where you're using this code.

Comment: @CalvinFurano Edited!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add a full answer because a moderator closed this question as duplicate. Your issue is in the way you're using the state hooks. accessToken and setAccessToken are independent. Calling setAccessToken does _not_ immediately change the `accessToken variable in the same call scope. Calling setAccessToken tells React what the _next_ state will be. React then calls the component function again to get the updated DOM. This second call will have the accessToken with the new state. In this way, state should only be used for things that affect the DOM, not for caching.

Comment: Here's a paste showing how you might move the tokens to the module scope:
https://pastebin.com/WZV7T9fE

Note: it's completely untested.

In reality you'd probably want to move the token caching code to your API layer, and make sure the React component is focusing on view logic.

Comment: @CalvinFurano Much much appreciated. Makes a lot of sense now. Thank you!